# What is the better way to store json data in postgresql?

Tags: json, database, postgresql

I have some json data which i am getting from a particular API. i am using postgresql as a db. What the best way to store the json data? Using row column format or saving the complete json data in a single field of jsonb type

Comment: This question is considered too broad for stackoverflow. It depends on many factors. Why do you want to store the data in a json field? Do you intend to update the data? Do you intend to query specific json fields (filter the data based on some parameters)?

Comment: No, I don't intend to update the data. I have a large collection of data, that I have to store approx 100k JSON objects. its a one-time insertion of data in Db. after insertion there will be no update there will only be SELECT queries.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience with Django using postgresql: I am used to store the raw json in a single field.
Next, I parse it according to my needs.